# How to write to DB using Linq

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a Database with a Table named `Fruits`. In the table I have 3 columns: `Name`, `Date`, `Remove`.

Now i have inserted 3 rows, with a value like

```
Apple----20/10/12----N
Mango----21/12/12----Y
Banana--- 15/07/12----N
Grapes----18/12/12----Y
```

I want to delete the 2 rows which is marked as 'Y.

This I want to achive using Linq in c# code. Initally I am establishing a connection to the DB using a connection string. I will get the device context DC, and with this I will copy all the rows.

Now I will enumerate the rows marked as `N` and I will call remove.

Once I do remov, I will do: `dc.deleteonSubmit<tableName>(var).`

After this, I should call `dc.submittsavechages();` or what to make DB look like:

```
Mango----21/12/12----Y
Grapes----18/12/12----Y
```

If I query in sql query analyzer i should get above result. How to do this in LINQ?

Comment: Linq to SQL or Linq to Entities? They are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim dc as new DataClassesDataContext()

Dim deleteFruits = _
    From f In db.Fruits() _
    Where f.Remove _
    Select f

For Each fruit In deleteFruits
    db.Fruits.DeleteOnSubmit(fruit)
Next

Try
    db.SubmitChanges()
Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine(ex)
    ' Provide for exceptions
End Try
```

Comment: Once we call that DeleteOnsubmit and commit SubmitChanges, it will work right?... so it will remove the rows present in the actual SQL DB correct?

Comment: Yes, providing you have set up your LINQ to SQL data context correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done more compact

```
db.Fruits.DeleteAllOnSubmit(db.Fruites.Where(f=>f.remove == "Y" ))
```

The `try/db.SubmitChanges()` part remains unchanged.

Comment: i am new to sql, i have one doubt.. How does your statement db.Fruites.Where(f=>f.remove) lists all the rows which are marked as 'Y'

Comment: Thanks but i have one more query... If the member is entity ref, then how to remove?...